# Variables updating issues using $digest() with angularjs & jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm having issues with the use of scope.$digest() when testing an angular directive.
When we see the angularjs tests, each time we compile an html piece of code to tests in it,               .$digest() is called to perform a scope life cycle.

My problem is that if I execute this function, the argument value of the widget is taken into account at the end of this method instead of using the parsed one.
If I don't execute the function, everything works right.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

I have created a codepen example: [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apAue)

```
var Widgets =  angular.module('myWidgets', ['ng']);
Widgets
.directive('widgetb', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            a: "@",
        },

        replace: true,
        template: "<div>" +
                        "{{a}}" +
                    "</div>",
        controller : function($scope) {
            $scope.action = function(action) {
                console.log("Action received");
                console.log(action);
            };
            $scope.a = parseInt($scope.a);
        }
    };
});

describe("Test", function() {
    var $compile, scope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('myWidgets');
    });
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, $rootScope) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));


    it('Compile', function() {
          var element = $compile('<widgetb a="3xx" />')(scope);
          var widget_scope = element.isolateScope();

          /* test ok if digest command is not executed, error otherwise */
          widget_scope.$digest();
          expect(widget_scope.a).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive controllers are not run once per `$digest` cycle, but template interpolation is. What you would want is a watcher in the controller to make sure that `$scope.a` is always kept an integer.

Basically what's going on is, when `widgetb` is being compiled into the scope, the controller runs. When there's no `scope.$digest`, the latest value of `$scope.a` comes from the controller. Once you call `scope.$digest()`, the template gets interpolated based on what was originally passed in. Since `@` is not two-way bound, as it's a primitive, it was not changed from when you called `parseInt` in the controller beforehand, so it gets "reset" to `3xx`.

Here's an updated codepen with the watcher installed. Tests pass:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ocKrF

Comment: I was afraid the watcher takes a lot of resources but it may be the only way to do this. Moreover, I've realized that we can modify the variable inside the watch function but a new watcher won't be fired, avoiding unnecessary watcher executions. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I was dealing with a similar issue a few weeks ago. Unfortunately it is difficult to keep a scope variable in integer form if it's passed in as a string, and I believe a watcher is the only way to preserve the change. An alternative would be to declare the integer as a variable in a parent scope and pass it as a 2-way `=` binding, but I felt that was out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Doing that we reduce the widget coupling making it parent dependent.  Returning into classic development, we can create a private variable in the controller accessible by public getter & setter and initialized with the input variable the first time. This may reduce the load performed by the watchers. In the other hand, I think this breaks in some way the declarative programming way of working with angular....

Comment: Yeah, this is true. If you're not expecting it to change after initialization you can also unbind the watcher by calling it inside of itself, but I'm unsure how that would behave in a test environment.

Comment: I meant augment coupling, sorry